# How to convert string with different parameters into integer?

Tags: python

I want to write function, in-order to convert string, with many parameters, into integer. Problem is, how to define?

Like

```
def function_average(numbers)
```

where numbers is one string.

I want

```
function_average('40,50,60')
>>> 50
```

without cutting into different strings, but in one.

I tried different methods, but always have a mistakes, like invalid syntax.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried, and the errors you got.

Comment: Also show us the expected result. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will rewrite!

Answer (score 1):

just guess, from your function name and parameters ...

```
def function_average(numbers):
    numbers_list = numbers.split(',')
    return sum([int(x) for x in numbers_list]) / len(numbers_list)


print(function_average('40,50,60'))
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. So, split will separate strings?

Comment: `sum(int(x) for x in numbers_list)` no need to make list, when you can use generator

Comment: But what about ('3.4,3.5,6.7')? Is it other split for such numbers? Oh, I got, need to use float, instead of integer. Thanks!

Comment: @LukaRahne, yes, for sum no need to make list, but also need get the length of the number list.